# How to calculate active & reactive power ripple?

Tags: power, ripple

Some control strategies (like : DPC, MPC...) suffers from the presence of active/reactive power ripples, which requires some additional methods to be taken to reduce those ripples.
But to judge the efficiency of those methods we need to calculate/quantify the value of the active and reactive power ripples, **how can we do that ?**

---

In his paper : [Low Complexity Model Predictive Control—Single Vector-Based Approach](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6665022/), Yongchang Zhang & WeiXie wrote :

> Table II lists the quantitative comparison of both methods in terms of
>   active power ripple, reactive power ripple, and current THD at two
>   operating points. **The power ripple is calculated using the standard**
>   **deviation function, which is expressed as :**

[image: equations]

> **where N is the sampling number of active power and reactive power in a**
>   **period of 0.1 s.**

I didn't understand this method of calculation,

what is this *standard deviation function* ? what is *pi* and *qi* ? how can we implement this calculation in an experimental setup ?

Comment: it's really weird that you understand control strategies, but you have not heard of deviation. So, here is the wiki article to start 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation.

pi, qi are samples of the original pq power and N the number of samples

\$p_{rip}\$ and \$q_{rip}\$ are equal to s = \$ \sqrt{ \frac{1}{N} Σ (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the wikipedia entry for [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation):

[image]

The equations above are the same calculation, but different notation

\$p_i\$ and \$q_i\$ are the samples, coming from a sampled vector (like data from an analog to digital converter)

$$ \mu = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i$$ means to average the values toghether
once you've computed the average, then you plug that into the other equation

If I have a vector of four values [1 5 2 3] the mean (using the above equation) would be 2.75

The standard deviation would be

$$ \sigma = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}([1,5,2,3 ]-2.75)=1.707$$

excel or any math package have the mean and std functions, or you could do this with a for loop and code.